# Selecting range vba

Tags: excel, vba, select

I wish to select a portion of a column from one workbook so I can copy and paste it into another.  I know the command to select the whole column and a defined section of the column but I am unsure how to do this in my case as I need to select from the 5th row to the last populated cell in that column.  I am rather new to vba so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last row value

```
Last =INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
fifthToLast=Last-5
```

to get the row value. Then to select it just do, presuming everything is in column A

```
Range(Cells(fifthToLast,1),Cells(Last,1)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells(1,1).Select
ActiveCell.Paste
```